# Visio 2013: Share a background page among multiple pages

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I have a simple Visio 2013 Drawing (document), with a single page and a separate "background page."

I have added a second (third, really) page to the Visio document. Instead of creating a new background page, I would like to share the background page that I created for the first page.

**NOTE**: I am using Microsoft Office 2013 Service Pack 1 on Windows 8.1 Professional Edition.

Answer (score 5):

To achieve this, follow these steps:

1. Create a new, blank page
2. Select the new page (if necessary)
3. Click on the `Design` tab
4. Click the small arrow on the bottom-right of `Page Setup`
   [image: Page Setup]
5. Click on the `Page Properties` tab in the `Page Setup` dialog box
6. Select the background page from the `Background` drop-down box
7. Click `OK`

[image: Page Properties]

Comment: This is splendid! It's simple, clear, and well illustrated, and it beats the pants off the page offered by Microsoft. Six years after @Trevor Sullivan posted it, it remains relevant and earned a bookmark. Thank you for your excellent post for this long-time Visio user who has been away from the program for several years. (I got my first copy in 1993, long before Microsoft bought the company.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your previously created background page. A background page can be used as the background for any number of foreground pages. And any foreground page can use any background page (if you have more than one). Just use the **Page Setup** dialog as per steps 5, 6 and 7 of Trevor's answer.